# Deserializing geoJSON in a Web API 2 controller in c#

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, asp.net-web-api2, geojson

I need to pass some JSON including a geoJSON object and have it deserialise to this model:

```
public class GeoTag
    {
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        public DbGeography Geography { get; set; }
        public string Tag { get; set; }
        public Guid UserID { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm using a Web API 2 controller in .NET 4.5 as follows:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(GeoTag))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostQuestion(GeoTag geoTag)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            //Do some stuff

            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = geoTag.ID }, geoTag);
        }
```

And here's my JSON:

```
{
"Tag": "food",
"Geography": {
"coordinates": ["-0.1337","51.50998"],
"type": "Point"
}
```

}

I'm having trouble getting the controller method to interprate the `Geography`; it's returning this message:

```
Unable to find a constructor to use for type System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography. A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute. Path 'Geography.coordinates', line 4, position 19.
```

Does anyone know if what I'm doing is possible or maybe my approach is wrong?

Comment: The Json sample that you provided isnt a valid Json.

Comment: First change your Json, It's not valid.

Comment: Change your Json like below answer.

Comment: Thanks @KiShOrE. I've changed the JSON as you described in the answer below but things still aren't working. I've updated this question and included the message returned from my web method.

Comment: `DbGeography` isn't GeoJSON.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Json like this,

`{
    "Tag": "food",
    "Geography": {
    "coordinates": ["-0.1337","51.50998"],
    "type": "Point"
    }
}`

It will work.. :)

Comment: Thanks @KiShOrE. I've changed the JSON but no joy. I've updated this question with your JSON and included the message returned from my web method. Any ideas?

Comment: I've added the message that's coming back to the question above: begins 'Unable to find a constructor to use for type System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography'

Comment: Try this link   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411572/unable-to-find-a-default-constructor-to-use-for-type-system-json-jsonobject